# Building invariant $S_n$ structures from two invariant $Z_n$ structures

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, finite-groups

Take two mathematical structures with a $Z_n$ symmetry (cyclic symmetry). Which are the different ways, in "gluing" these structures, to obtain a mathematical structure with a $S_n$ symmetry (permutation symmetry) ?

---

The motivation comes from  physics, with a geometric example:

Take one $D_2$ disk, with n indexed "intervals" "punctures" ($I_1, I_2, .... I_n$) living on the boundary $S_1$ of the  $D_2$ disk. There is a $Z_n$ symmetry, but not a $S_n$ symmetry, because the "intervals" "punctures" cannot cross each over (there is only one dimension on $S_1$)

Take an other identical disk, with n indexed "intervals" "punctures" ($I'_1, I'_2, .... I'_n$)

Now, we are gluing the two structures. We deform the two disks as half-spheres, and gluing them at the equator, to obtain a 2-Sphere. We deform each interval $I_i$ or $I'_i$ as a litte half-circle, and gluing, at the equator,  each couple of indexed "intervals" "punctures" ($I_i,I'_i$"), so that we obtain n indexed little disk boundaries  $D_1, D_2, ......D_n$, at the surface of the sphere.

But now, we have a permutation $S_n$ symmetry, because, roughly speaking, we can freely move the little  boudaries $D_1, D_2, ......D_n$ at the surface of the sphere , and so exchange their place.

Comment: I think I understand the gluing process, but I don't think I understand the question. There are $n$ ways in which you can match up the intervals, but you're probably aware of that -- what else do you want to know?

Comment: My question was a general question about mathematic structures. I gave a geometric example, but the question is wider.   The idea is to begin with 2 structures (not necessary geometric) which have a cyclic symmetry $Z_n$, and build an other structure, which has a permutation symmetry $S_n$. I wondered if somebody had an example of this building.